# Show all data in the same row in Framework Manager Cognos

Tags: cognos

I'm using IBM Cognos Framework Manager/Report Author 10.2.1

The Data looks like the following for two rows:

```
**Case ID    Activity              Date Updated**

11111        Bill Paid             09/25/2015
11111        Received Bill         08/01/2015
```

On my report, I need to show the following for the same exact Case:

```
**Case ID    LAST Activity     LATEST ACTIVITY      Date Updated**

11111        Received Bill     Bill Paid           09/25/2015
```

Received Paid needs to show in the same Row showing the latest
information with the 09/25/2015 Date.

Not sure how to do this in the report or even Framework Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky but a worthy question as you come across this type of data modeling regularly. I can give you a solution in the report.

The two bits you need to figure out is the maximum 'Date Updated' for each ID and the next to maximum 'Date Updated' for each ID.

Create a new data item called 'Max Date' with the following expression:

```
maximum([Date Updated] for [Case ID])
```

Create another new data item called 'Next Max Date' with the following expression:

```
maximum(
CASE 
WHEN [Date Updated] <> [Max Date] THEN [Date Updated] 
ELSE null 
END
for [Case ID])
```

Create another data item called 'Latest Activity' with the following expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN [Date Updated] = [Max Date] THEN [Activity] 
ELSE null
END
```

Create yet another data item called 'LAST Activity' with the following expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN [Date Update] = [Next Max Date] THEN [Activity]
ELSE null
END
```

Set the 'Aggregate Function' property of both 'Latest Activity' and 'LAST Activity' to 'Maximum'.

**Summary**

We calculate the maximum date for each Case ID. Next we use a CASE statement to exclude the rows that correspond to the max date and then get a maximum for each Case ID of all other rows. We create a new data item that will spit out the Activity if the date matches the max date otherwise null is emitted. We create a second data item that outputs the Activity if the date matches the next to max date otherwise spits out null. We set the aggregate function for both to 'Maximum' which has the effect of getting rid of any null values in those columns through the auto-group and summarize process. This leaves us with two new columns on each row showing the activity of the latest and the one before that.

Comment: It is certainly tricky for sure. Your solution recommendation worked greatly after trying the same exercise within my environment. It is very quick also. I also appreciate the final paragraph explaining the approach in details. Thank you so much for your time.